# SplineDegree->1 does not work with BezierFunction?

Tags: functions, options, implementation-details, splines, function-comparison

This works (`SplineDegree -> 2`)

```
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 2}}, SplineDegree -> 2][u], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image: BezierFunction SplineDegree 2]

but this does not (`SplineDegree -> 1`)

```
ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 0.5}, {2, 2}}, SplineDegree -> 1][u], {u, 0, 1}]
```

> BezierFunction::invdeg: Value of option SplineDegree -> 1 should be a positive integer, or a list of positive integers

I found no reference to a possible issue in [the documentation for `BezierFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BezierFunction.html).

`SplineDegree -> 1` works fine with `BSplineFunction` and `BezierCurve`; shouldn't it also work with `BezierFunction`?

(Mma 8.0.4 Mac OSX)

Comment: The only value that seems to work for an arbitrary list of values seems to be the length of the list minus 1.

Comment: When you look at the [definition of Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Generalization) you can see why the degree of the polynomial has to be equal to the number of points minus one, like Heike pointed out. The error message could be more helpful here, though.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke And yet SplineDegree->1 works for BezierCurve[]? You get straight lines when you put that in a Graphics[]. What am I missing?

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke And moreover, the option `SplineDegree` which is explicitly mentioned in the docs for `BezierFunction` is then completely misleading because it suggests that the function works just like `BezierCurve`. So my guess is that they _did_ mean to make these two functions work the same way, but forgot to partition the argument lis of `BezierFunction` according to the `SplineDegree` when it's explicitly given.

Comment: Yes, this could definitely be improved on Wolfram's side. It is confusing as it is at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Reason for incompatibility

Yes, the doc shouldn't mention that it is *fully* compatible (that's an oversight...). `BSplineFunction` and `BSplineCurve` are fully compatible as far as I remember, but not `BezierCurve` and `BezierFunction`.

The reason is that what `BezierCurve` is doing when it has more than `d+1` control points for `SplineDegree->d` case is something called composite Bezier curve. Essentially, the remainder of control points are grouped in `d` points, and creating degree `d` spline by carrying the last point from the previous curve.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}, {8, -1}, {9, 1}, {10, -2}};

Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: composite bezier]

It is a convenient hack that graphics / CAD people has been using for a long time, and it makes sense when you are creating multiple continuous curve segments.

[image: not c1]

But the problem with it for `BezierFunction` is that:

1. it does not guarantee the continuous derivative at the connection points (which are marked with blue circles). It only guarantees $C^0$:
2. Another problem is parametrization. Should parameters run between 0 to 1 (by uniformly dividing by the number of curve segments), or what... None of this is a problem for graphics primitives.
3. This idea is not working well in multi-dimensional case (it can be extended, but no one uses it and has no mathematical meaning).
4. There are few mathematical ways to make the connection $C^d$ when $d$ is the degree, nonetheless (introducing intermediate control points or using smoothing function), but then it is not matching with `BezierCurve` either.

So, we decided not to support it.

## Work around

1. `SplineDegree->1` case: Just use `BSplineFunction`. It is exactly the same parametrization, running between 0 to 1, uniformly divided by the number of line segments.
2. `SplineDegree->d` where `d > 1`: `CompositeBezierFunction` code will be provided.

Comment: Taken up by work. I will try to finish up the code and modify the post soon.

Comment: Couldn't `BezierFunction` simply act like your `CompositeBezierFunction` whenever a non-maximal `SplineDegree` is explicitly specified?

Comment: @Yu-SungChang I just want to remind you that you promised to provide the `CompositeBezierFunction` code.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a function like what @yu-sung-chang was suggesting.

```
compositeBezierPoints[bezierCurvePoints_, degree_Integer] :=
Select[
  Partition[bezierCurvePoints, UpTo[degree + 1], 1][[1 ;; -1 ;; degree]],
  Length[#] > 1 &]

compositeBezierPoints[bezierCurvePoints_, 1] :=
Select[
  Partition[bezierCurvePoints, UpTo[2], 1],
  Length[#] > 1 &]
```

If you input the points of the BezierCurve, and the degree (Automatic is degree 3), then `compositeBezierPoints` breaks up the points into a new set of points expected by `BezierFunction`. You would map `BezierFunction` over this list to get a list of functions that are each parameterized from 0 to 1. Here's a Manipulate showing the equivalence for a range of degrees:

```
pts = Table[{i, RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 15}];
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}], 
    ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[Through[(BezierFunction /@ compositeBezier[pts, d])[t]]],
      {t, 0, 1}], 
    Graphics[{Black, Dashed, BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> d]}]],
  {d, 1, 6, 1}]
```

You can re-parameterize the composite parts into a Piecewise function that itself runs from 0 to 1. I use `BezierSymbolicFunction` (found somewhere on MSE) to get the arc lengths in order to scale the segments:

```
BezierSymbolicFunction[pts_?MatrixQ] :=
Function[Evaluate[Sum[pts[[i+1]] BernsteinBasis[Length[pts]-1, i, #], {i, 0, Length[pts]-1}]]]

makeBezierPiecewise[bezierCurvePoints_, degree_Integer] :=
Module[{symbolicSegments, bezierSegments, lengths, ends},
  symbolicSegments = BezierSymbolicFunction /@ compositeBezier[bezierCurvePoints, degree];
  bezierSegments = BezierFunction /@ compositeBezier[bezierCurvePoints, degree];
  lengths = ArcLength[#[t], {t, 0, 1}]& /@ symbolicSegments;
  ends = Prepend[Accumulate[lengths/Total[lengths]], 0.];
  Function[Evaluate[
    Piecewise[
      Table[
        {
          bezierSegments[[i]][(#-ends[[i]])/(ends[[i+1]] - ends[[i]])],
          ends[[i]] < # <= ends[[i+1]]},
        {i, 1, Length[ends]-1}]]]]]
```