# How can I adaptively simplify a curved shape?

Tags: graphics, interpolation, symbols, approximation

For the purposes of creating a [publication-quality plot marker](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84857/280) I wish to convert a font glyph into a simplified `Polygon` where points are taken adaptively according to curvature of the boundary. Unfortunately the `MaxCellMeasure` option of the built-in `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` often does the opposite thing: the higher the value of this option, the lesser points it takes in the areas of high curvature but at the same time it keeps large number of points in the areas of low curvature! It is unbelievable but true, look at this (I highlighted the regions with highest curvature by red rectangles):

```
Table[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold]], _Text, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> m, MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> Directive[Black, PointSize[.015]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, 
  Epilog -> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Rectangle[{1.7, -2}, {3, -4.5}], 
    Rectangle[{-1.7, 2}, {-3, 4.5}]}],
 {m, .2, 1.2, .4}]
```

> [image: output]

**How to obtain an *adaptive* approximation of a curved shape with a polygon?**

Comment: Does `SimplifyLine` from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102618/12) help?

Comment: Not a solution to the main problem, but note that `MaxCellMeasure` quantifies the size of one cell and not the number of cells. Hence, it makes sense that a larger value here leads to fewer cells in total (including at the points of high curvature).

Comment: Why not use: `First @ ImportString @ ExportString[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold], "PDF"]`?

Comment: I got this from `SimplifyLine`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nHxs1.png

Comment: @Szabolcs This is very close to what I need, please post this as an answer! Probably starting from larger number of initial points would allow to get almost perfect result.

Comment: @CarlWoll It returns a `FilledCurve` containing a set of `BezierCurve`s which I need to approximate with a `Polygon`.

Comment: Unrelated: you can simply add `MeshCellStyle -> {0 -> Red}` in BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics to visualize the points.

Comment: Why does it need to be a Polygon?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, edited.

Comment: For a plot marker, isn't a BezierCurve actually better than a Polygon? It takes less space (say, when exported to PDF), and it is more accurate.  I know it's called *polygon* plot markers, but we don't have to take it literally :)

Comment: @CarlWoll In this concrete case it is due to design of the [``PolygonPlotMarkers` ``  package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84857/280). But the problem has higher applicability, for example vector [text on a curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16194/280) may look better when we use polyline approximation instead of `BezierCurve`s.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, but when developing the package I also think about the reverse task: someone may wish to recover the original data from the PDF. When markers are (anti)symmetric polygons, the solution is straightforward and obvious: one needs just to take the mean of the coordinates of the vertices in order to obtain the center of the marker. With `BezierCurve`s the situation is not so clear.

Comment: So, the only reason to use `Polygon` is because it is easier to find the center? I don't think it is difficult to find the center of a `FilledCurve`, can't you just use something like `AbsoluteOptions[Graphics[FilledCurve[..]], PlotRange]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Not in this sense: I mean recovering the original data from a figure in published PDF file. With years such file often becomes the only source of the original data...

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually approximating polygon can take lesser space than `BezierCurve`s as I show in "Update" section of my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138012/280).

Answer (score 37):

We can use the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm to reduce the number of points.  This algorithm was originally devised for processing map data.

```
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
  Text[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold]],
  _Text]

poly = First@reg["BoundaryPolygons"];

pts = SimplifyLine[First[poly], 0.02];
Graphics@{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Polygon[pts], Point[pts]}
```

[image]

The second argument of `SimplifyLine` is the smallest length that you care about.  If we have two line segments defined by three points, $A$, $B$, $C$, then the algorithm removes $B$ if it is further than this length from the line $AC$.

Thus this algorithm does not deal with angles, and will smoothen out rough curves with sharp turns at small spatial scales.

For your use case, it may be better to use an angle-based criterion for removing points, similar to the adaptive sampling that `Plot` does. That actually gives some ideas: Perhaps you could create an interpolating function through the letter outline, then plot it using `ParametricPlot` and tune `MaxRecursion` and `PlotPoints`.

---

This is the implementation of the line simplification. I have had this code for a long time and I haven't actually looked through it before posting it here.  If you find a problem with it, let me know.

```
SimplifyLine::usage = "SimplifyLine[points, threshold] will simplify a path given as a set of points.  The default method is Ramer-Douglas-Peucker."

rot[{x_, y_}] := {y, -x}

Options[SimplifyLine] = {Method -> "RamerDouglasPeucker"}

SimplifyLine::method = "Unknown method: ``.";

SimplifyLine[points_, threshold_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
    With[{method = OptionValue[Method]},
      Switch[method,
        "RamerDouglasPeucker", rdp[DeleteDuplicates[points, #1 == #2 &], threshold],
        _, Message[SimplifyLine::method, method]; $Failed
      ]
    ]

rdp[{p1_, p2_}, _] := {p1, p2}
rdp[points_, th_] :=
    Module[{p1 = First[points], p2 = Last[points], b, dist, maxPos},
      b = Normalize@rot[p2 - p1];
      dist = Abs[b.(# - p1) & /@ points];
      maxPos = First@Ordering[dist, -1];
      If[
        dist[[maxPos]] < th
        ,
        {p1, p2},
        rdp[points[[;; maxPos]], th] ~Join~ Rest@rdp[points[[maxPos ;;]], th]
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: Related Demonstration by Mark McClure: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolylineSimplification/

Comment: As I understand, `SimplifyLine` doesn't take into account that we have closed curve and should treat list of points as cyclic, it never removes first and last points.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Yes, that is correct. It might be better to split the data into two segments and apply the algorithm separately.

Comment: You mean, two overlapping segments? Without overlaps we'll get fixed boundary points again.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Maybe something like [this](http://pastebin.com/hBPfGN9U). It splits the closed curve into two open curves at the topmost and bottommost (ymax, ymin) points, and applies simplification separately.

Comment: With this method the topmost and bottommost points are fixed and can't be removed. Consider the case of glyph "Z": after converting into boundary mesh it'll have many redundant topmost and bottommost points with identical $y$ coordinates... The same is true for many other glyphs.

Comment: Yes, the two endpoints will always be fixed and cannot be removed.  But it is always only two points, even for a letter Z.  This means that the top and bottom segment of the Z may each use 3 points instead of only two endpoints. Thus there will be some redundancy, but not much.  Your angle based method will not have this problem.

Comment: Finally I come to dividing the original shape into two parts but for another reason: the marker should be (anti)symmetric. With `SimplifyCurve` I got a very nice result in this way, see my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138348/280).

Comment: The pairwise compare of `DeleteDuplicates[points, #1 == #2 &]` is very expensive as [known](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17042/121).  What is its purpose here?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do not remember ... I wrote the code years before I posted it here. I should have commented it better, but I did not. I may have run into tolerance problems. As I remember there are cases when `a==b` is `True` but `DeleteDuplicates[{a,b}]` does not remove one of the elements because there is a tiny difference between them.

Comment: Do you have interest in revisiting and optimizing this code?  If so I may wait for you to do that; if not I may try myself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Beyond this one point that you mentioned, I do not have time to revise it right now. If you would like to do that, that would be great. I know that it is not very fast.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my attempt to use `ParametricPlot` for obtaining an *adaptive* approximation of the shape. It is based on the code of [glyph to `Polygon` conversion engine by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18760/280). The latter converts `BezierCurve`s directly into `BezierFunction`s (as [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` does](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98162/280)) what isn't correct in general since these functions are [compatible](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8240/280) only for `BezierCurve`s of the form `BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> Length[pts] - 1]`. Happily, it seems that `BezierCurve`s obtained from glyphs always have this property.

Here is slightly simplified version of Simon's function for decoding `FilledCurves`:

```
filledCurveToBeziers[fc_FilledCurve] := MapThread[processFCdata, List @@ fc];

processFCdata[desc_, pts_] := Module[{r, sd},
   r = Range @@@ Partition[Prepend[Accumulate[desc[[All, 2]]], 1], 2, 1];
   BezierFunction[pts[[#]]] & /@ r];
```

I choose `PlotPoints -> 2` for having initial points at the start and the end of each Bézier curve and plot them with different values of `MaxRecursion` option:

```
fc = Cases[ImportString[
    ExportString[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold], 
     "PDF"]], _FilledCurve, -1];
beziers = filledCurveToBeziers /@ fc;
plots = Table[
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[#[t] & /@ Flatten[beziers]], {t, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> r, 
   Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[.015]], PlotPoints -> 2, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> MaxRecursion -> r], {r, 0, 2}]
```

> [image: plots]

Unfortunately with `MaxRecursion` up to `2` addition of `Method -> {"Refinement" -> {"ControlValue" -> maxBend}}` (as well as `Method -> {MaxBend -> maxBend*°}`) doesn't affect the result unless we set `maxBend = 180` degrees effectively switching off the recursive subdivision. Hence in this situation `ParametricPlot` is almost equivalent to uniform sampling:

```
samples[m_] := Thread[#[Range[0, 1, 1/2^m]]] & /@ Flatten[beziers]

Table[Graphics[
  MapIndexed[{PointSize[.015], Point[#], ColorData[97, #2[[1]]], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], 
     Line[#]} &, samples[m]], ImageSize -> 300], {m, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plots]

---

Another approach it to create an interpolating function from the uniformly sampled points and then apply `ParametricPlot` for obtaining *adaptive* sampling:

```
pl = ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@BSplineFunction[Flatten[samples[5], 1], SplineDegree -> 1][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, PointSize[0.015]], MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 20, Axes -> False]
```

> [image: plot]

As seen from the plot, the disadvantage of this method is difficulty in reproducing sharp corners what requires large values of `MaxRecursion` leading to large number of sampled points. In this concrete case it is easy to select the sharp corners from the list of control points:

```
clpts = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[samples[0], 1], Equal];
cornerPoints = 
  Flatten[Select[Split[clpts, First[#1] == First[#2] || Last[#1] == Last[#2] &], 
    Length[#] > 1 &], 1];
Show[pl, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.015], Point[cornerPoints]}]
```

> [image: plot]

Addition of them to the new adaptive sample could improve the approximation but it will still contain a lot of redundant points.

---

The obvious conclusion is that we need an angle-based simplification algorithm, not an adaptive refinement algorithm.

Answer (score 11):

Here I present a very simple angle-based polygon reduction algorithm as described in the chapter "A Simple Algorithm" of [David Eberly's "Polyline Reduction"](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/PolylineReduction.pdf). The only addition is that I treat the list as cyclic since we work with closed polygon, not with an open polyline. The algorithm is vastly inefficient and has no quality control (other than visual), but demonstrates the idea.

Outlining the glyph, decoding `FilledCurve`s and performing uniform sampling on each of the Bézier curves:

```
filledCurveToBeziers[fc_FilledCurve] := MapThread[processFCdata, List @@ fc];

processFCdata[desc_, pts_] := 
  Module[{r, sd}, r = Range @@@ Partition[Prepend[Accumulate[desc[[All, 2]]], 1], 2, 1];
   BezierFunction[pts[[#]]] & /@ r];

fc = Cases[ImportString[
    ExportString[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold], 
     "PDF"]], _FilledCurve, -1];
beziers = filledCurveToBeziers /@ fc;

sample[n_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Thread[#[Range[0, 1, 1/n]]] & /@ Flatten[beziers], 1], Equal]

list = sample[3];
```

The implementation (as weighting function for vertex I use `π` minus vector angle at the vertex):

```
nextPoint[list_] := 
  Ordering[Pi - Re@VectorAngle[#2 - #1, #2 - #3] & @@@ 
    Partition[ArrayPad[list, {{1, 1}}, "Periodic"], 3, 1], 1];
deleteOnePoint[{pointToDelete_, list_}] := 
  With[{listNext = Delete[list, pointToDelete]}, {nextPoint[listNext], listNext}];
```

Pre-computing data for each frame in `Manipulate`:

```
seq = NestList[deleteOnePoint, {nextPoint[list], list}, Length[list] - 6];
```

Now everything is ready for the demonstration:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Text[
    Row[{Dynamic[Length[list] - n], " points"}, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 22], 
    Scaled[{.5, .5}]], EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[.015]}], 
   FaceForm[None], {Red, PointSize[.04], Point[seq[[n + 1, 2]][[seq[[n + 1, 1]]]]], 
    Polygon[seq[[n + 1, 2]]], Yellow, PointSize[.015], Point[seq[[n + 1, 2]]]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {3, 19}}], {n, 0, Length[seq] - 1, 1, AnimationRate -> 5, 
  Appearance -> "Open", RefreshRate -> 60}]
```

> [image: animation]

---

#### Update: using another weighting function

A bit of experimentation showed that much better results can be obtained with more sophisticated weighting function:

```
nextPoint[list_] := 
  Ordering[((Pi - Re@VectorAngle[#2 - #1, #2 - #3])*
            (Norm[#2 - #1] Norm[#2 - #3])/(Norm[#2 - #1] + Norm[#2 - #3])) & @@@
                       Partition[ArrayPad[list, {{1, 1}}, "Periodic"], 3, 1], 1];
```

Selecting more initial sampling points allows to get better approximation:

```
list = sample[30];

seq = NestList[deleteOnePoint, {nextPoint[list], list}, Length[list] - 6];
```

Here is `Manipulate` where at the top at left shown current approximation and on the right shown initial sample:

```
c = RegionCentroid[Polygon[list]];
Manipulate[Graphics[{Text[
    Row[{Dynamic[Length[list] - n], " points"}, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 22], 
    Scaled[{.15, .92}]], EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[.015]}], FaceForm[None], Red, 
   PointSize[.04], Point[seq[[n + 1, 2]][[seq[[n + 1, 1]]]]], Polygon[seq[[n + 1, 2]]], 
   Yellow, PointSize[.015], Point[seq[[n + 1, 2]]], EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01]}], 
   Translate[Scale[Polygon[seq[[n + 1, 2]]], 1/20, c], {-.5, 9}], 
   Translate[Scale[Polygon[list], 1/20, c], {.5, 9}], EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Blue], 
   Translate[Scale[Polygon[seq[[n + 1, 2]]], 1/20, c], {-.5, 10}], 
   Translate[Scale[Polygon[list], 1/20, c], {.5, 10}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {3, 22}}], {{n, Length[list] - 50}, Length[list] - 70, 
  Length[seq] - 1, 1, AnimationRate -> 5, AnimationRepetitions -> None, 
  RefreshRate -> 60}]
```

> [image: output]

As one can see, an approximation containing only 50 points is indistinguishable from the original at the usual letter sizes. For comparison, the original Bézier curves extracted from the glyph contain 101 control points...

Comment: Which one do you think works better in practice for your use case? The angle based one or the distance based one?

Comment: @Szabolcs Up to now my experiments show that both methods give very similar results with main difference that Ramer-Douglas-Peucker can't drop junky first and last points because it can't treat the points cyclically.

Answer (score 2):

### Making antisymmetric curvilinear marker "S"

Here I present an approach used for making the `"Sl"` marker of my [package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85094/280). I start from the letter "S" of the font "Verdana", then take only its upper part, simplify it using [`SimplifyLine`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137945/280) and rationalize the result. Finally I get an antisymmetric shape described only by $17\times2=34$ points which at the usual letter and plot marker scales is indistinguishable from the non-simplified one.

For sampling the letter I use slightly simplified code of [Simon Wood's glyph to `Polygon` conversion engine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18760/280):

```
filledCurveToBeziers[fc_FilledCurve] := MapThread[processFCdata, List @@ fc];

processFCdata[desc_, pts_] := 
  Module[{r, sd}, r = Range @@@ Partition[Prepend[Accumulate[desc[[All, 2]]], 1], 2, 1];
   BezierFunction[pts[[#]]] & /@ r];

fc = Cases[ImportString[
    ExportString[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 13], 
     "PDF"]], _FilledCurve, -1];

beziers = filledCurveToBeziers /@ fc;

sample[n_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Thread[#[Range[0, 1, 1/n]]] & /@ Flatten[beziers], 1], Equal]
```

### The procedure

Taking initial sample:

```
list = sample[100];
```

Since letter "S" from the font "Verdana" has no symmetry, its half-height can be found only approximately:

```
ycApprox = Mean[list[[;; , 2]]];
```

For half-width we accept the half-width of the whole (or equivalently, of the bottom half of) letter "S":

```
xc = Mean[MinMax@list[[;; , 1]]];
```

Our goal is to make anti-symmetric "S". For this purpose we'll take the upper half of "S" from the "Verdana" font and then reflect it relative to center in order to get complete antisymmetric "S". For this purpose in turn we should find the place where we can stitch together the upper half with its reflected copy without introducing artifacts.

Select and visualize the central region of the original figure:

```
lines = Select[list, ycApprox - 2 < #[[2]] < ycApprox + 2 &];
Graphics[{Blue, Line[lines]}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graphics]

Split it into two separate lines:

```
lines = Split[lines, Abs[First@Subtract[##]] < 1 &];
Graphics[{Blue, Line /@ lines}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graphics]

Interpolate each of the lines and plot them:

```
Clear[x]
{if1, if2} = 
  Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 2, 
     "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}] & /@ lines;
Plot[{if1[x], if2[x]}, {x, 1, 13}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: plot]

Find the point where they have equal derivatives. It will be the splice point:

```
xJoin = x /. FindRoot[Equal @@ D[{if1[x], if2[x]}, x], {x, 7}];
```

Now we can find the actual vertical center of the future letter:

```
yc = Mean@{if1[2 xc - xJoin], if2[xJoin]};
```

... and find what exactly will be the upper half of the new shape:

```
halfList = Take[list, 
   Sort@Flatten[
     Position[list, #] & /@ 
      First /@ Nearest[list, {{xJoin, if2[xJoin]}, {2 xc - xJoin, if1[2 xc - xJoin]}}]]];
```

The center of the future shape will be placed at `{0, 0}`:

```
halfList = # - {xc, yc} & /@ halfList;
Graphics[{Blue, Line[halfList], Red, Line[-halfList]}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graphics]

```
list2 = Join[halfList, -halfList];
Graphics[{Blue, Line[list2]}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: graphics]

Simplifying the half of the letter and dropping one of the bounding points (they will be duplicated after reflection):

```
halfListS = Rest@SimplifyLine[halfList, .2];
```

Rationalizing the result:

```
halfListS = Rationalize[halfListS, .01];
```

Making the complete letter (reflecting and joining the points):

```
list3 = Join[#, -#] &@halfListS;
```

Visual evaluation. Comparing simplified and non-simplified antisymmetric symbol "S":

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Polygon[list3], Translate[Polygon[list2], {15.5, 0}],
  Text[Style["Simplified", 22], {0.875, 9}], Text[Style["Original", 22], {15.5 - 0.875, 9}], 
  Gray, Line[{{{-6, 7.5}, {-6, 8}, {7.6, 8}, {7.6, 7.5}}, {{7.9, 7.5}, {7.9, 8}, {21.5, 8}, {21.5, 7.5}}}],
  EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[],
  EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[1]], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, 6}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, 6}]},
  EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[2]], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, 4}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, 4}]},
  EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[3]], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, 2}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, 2}]},
  EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Black],
  FaceForm[Black], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, 0}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, 0}]},
  FaceForm[Blue], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, -2}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, -2}]},
  FaceForm[Green], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, -4}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, -4}]},
  FaceForm[Red], {Translate[Polygon[.1 list3], {7, -6}], Translate[Polygon[.1 list2], {8.5, -6}]}
  }, ImageSize -> 720]
```

> [image: graphics]

The half-marker as list of points:

```
halfListS
```

> ```
> {{-(49/16), -(3/11)}, {-(14/3), 9/11}, {-(38/7), 31/12}, {-(67/13), 37/8}, 
>  {-(26/7), 81/13}, {-(17/12), 71/10}, {7/4, 113/16}, {53/11, 31/5}, 
>  {53/11, 57/14}, {27/10, 46/9}, {5/14, 50/9}, {-(12/7), 91/17}, {-(31/10), 94/21},
>  {-(7/2), 13/4}, {-(157/52), 57/29}, {-(17/9), 11/8}, {2/5, 9/10}}
> ```

```
% // Length
```

> ```
> 17
> ```