# How to make a cow smaller (in BubbleChart3D plot)

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, markov-chains

I've been using random walk Metropolis to sample from the (unnormalised distribution) which is defined as $p(r)\propto e^{-100 r}$, where $r$ is the perpendicular distance of a point in 3D space from the surface of the cow:

[image: the cow]

The code to do so is,

```
polygonCoords = Flatten[Cases[Normal[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]], 
Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, {0, Infinity}], 1];



fPDF[aPoint__, lPolygonCoords__] := Module[{aMin = 
                                    Min[EuclideanDistance[#, aPoint] & /@ lPolygonCoords]}, Exp[-100 aMin]]
fStep[aPoint__, aStepSize_] :=RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[aPoint, 
                                   aStepSize  IdentityMatrix[3]], {1}][[1]]
fAcceptStep[aPoint_, aStepSize_, lPolygonCoords__] :=  Module[{aProposed = fStep[aPoint, aStepSize], aRand = RandomReal[], r}, r = fPDF[aProposed, lPolygonCoords]/
fPDF[aPoint, lPolygonCoords]; If[r > aRand, aProposed, aPoint]]
fMetropolis[numSteps_Integer, aStart__, aStepSize_, lPolygonCoords__] := NestList[fAcceptStep[#, aStepSize, lPolygonCoords] &, aStart, numSteps]
data = Flatten[ParallelTable[
                           fMetropolis[1000, {0, 0, 0}, 0.001, polygonCoords], {i, 1, 4, 1}],1];
```

which generates sample paths over time that look like,

[image: paths over the cow]

I want to draw a 3D point plot of all the sampled values where each of the points is a cow shape. I have tried doing this with,

```
n=10;
BubbleChart3D[
 Thread[{data[[1 ;; n, 1]], data[[1 ;; n, 2]], data[[1 ;; n, 3]], 
   ConstantArray[0.1, n]}], ChartElements -> aCow, 
 ChartStyle -> Black, BubbleSizes -> {0.02, 0.04}]
```

which does work for a small number of points (10 in the below case),

[image: cow bubbles]

However, it does not scale well to 1000s of points, which is unsurprising given that each cow is a fairly complex 3D graphic. I have tried downsampling the cow's polygon coordinates and using these as markers instead by,

```
lRandomComponents = RandomInteger[{1, 5804}, 2000];

aLowResCow = 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], 
   Polygon[#, VertexColors -> Table[Hue[0, 0, 0], {Length[#]}]] & /@ 
    Cases[Normal[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]], 
      Polygon[x_, ___] :> x, {0, Infinity}][[lRandomComponents]]}]
```

which generates a fragmented cow,

[image: cow pieces]

but using these doesn't really work on the BubbleChart3D plot (they are shaded grey -- I want them black -- and don't look much like cows).

Does anyone have any idea how I can generate a 3D point plot like what I want without having an enormous file size and taking my computer a day to produce? If it helps, I don't need to be able to rotate such a plot in 3D.

Comment: I expect if you immediately `Rasterize` your file size will drop considerably. Just set the `ViewPoint` and things on the chart properly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the file size is only part of the issue. My computer will never manage to produce such a plot (of such size). I have no doubt that for 10,000 cows, the memory it takes will be untenable. I’ve edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to make a cow out of randomly sampled smaller cows?

Comment: Artistic want. (It's for a lecture.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that can show 1000 cows using 1.45MB.

The idea is to project the 3D cow onto a 2D plane and then use this as the `ChartElement` with `Inset`. The advantage to using `Inset` is the face will not rotate when rotating the graphic.

To project into 2D, I approximate the shape for the sake of speed and size of the mesh.

```
Options[approximateProjectedMeshRegion] = {RasterSize -> Automatic, 
  "NumPoints" -> Automatic, Method -> Automatic};

approximateProjectedMeshRegion[mr_, vp_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{n, num, rand, θ, bds, xd, yd, xmin, ymin, raw, im},
    n = Replace[OptionValue[RasterSize], Except[_Integer?Positive] -> 90, {0}];
    num = Replace[OptionValue["NumPoints"], Except[_Integer?Positive] -> 200000, {0}];

    rand = RandomPoint[mr, num];
    rand = RotationMatrix[{vp, {0, 0, 1}}].Transpose[rand];

    θ = VectorAngle[(RotationMatrix[{vp, {0,0,1}}].{0,0,1})[[1;;2]], {0, 1}];
    rand = Transpose[RotationMatrix[-θ].rand[[1;;2]]];

    bds = MinMax /@ Transpose[rand];
    {xd, yd} = Abs[Subtract @@@ bds]/n;
    {xmin, ymin} = bds[[All, 1]];

    raw = Transpose[{
        Clip[n+1 - Round[Divide[#2 - ymin, yd]], {1, n}],
        Clip[Round[Divide[#1 - xmin, xd]], {1, n}]
      }& @@ Transpose[rand]
    ];

    im = Image[SparseArray[Thread[Union[raw] -> 1]]];

    ImageMesh[im, Method -> OptionValue[Method], DataRange -> bds]
  ]
```

The approximated cow:

```
bmr2D = approximateProjectedMeshRegion[cow, {1.3, -2.4, 2.}]
```

[image]

This is a poor looking approximation, but that's ok. With 1000 cows, you won't notice the jagged corners. Moreover, it's small in size:

```
facepts = MeshPrimitives[bmr2D, 2][[1, 1]];
ByteCount[Graphics3D[Inset[Graphics[Polygon[facepts]]]]]
```

> ```
> 1328
> ```

Now unfortunately `BubbleChart3D` does not seem to accept `Inset` inside `ChartElements`, so we need to workaround. What we'll do is manually place the cows and use the options returned from `BubbleChart3D`.

```
n = 1000;
chartopts = Options[BubbleChart3D[Thread[{
  data[[1 ;; n, 1]], data[[1 ;; n, 2]], data[[1 ;; n, 3]], ConstantArray[0.1, n]}]
]];

scene = Graphics3D[
  Inset[Graphics[Polygon[facepts]], #, Center, 15] & /@ data[[1 ;; n]], 
  chartopts, 
  ImageSize -> Large
];
```

Here's its size:

```
ByteCount[scene]
```

> ```
> 1458864
> ```

Compare this to the size of 1000 cow's from `ExampleData`:

```
1000 ByteCount[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}]]
```

> ```
> 1399072000
> ```

And here's the scene:

```
scene
```

[image]

And like I said earlier, if you rotate the graphic the cows will face the same direction:
[image]

Comment: If you want a better looking 2D cow, you can do `bmr2D = approximateProjectedMeshRegion[cow, {1.3, -2.4, 2.}, 
 RasterSize -> 200, "NumPoints" -> 1000000]`. This will double the size of the final scene.

Comment: And another way is to do `bmr2D = ImageMesh[ColorNegate@Binarize[Rasterize[cow], .999]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this just to demonstrate another method to get the cow's silhouette.

```
cow = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"];
```

Get the parameters for the projection plane:

```
cc = RegionCentroid[cow];
nrm = Flatten[Last[SingularValueDecomposition[
                   Standardize[MeshCoordinates[cow], Mean, 1 &], -1, Tolerance -> 0]]];
```

Now, pick out faces "above" the projection plane:

```
facs = Select[TranslationTransform[-cc] @@@ MeshPrimitives[cow, 2],
              VectorQ[#.nrm, Positive] &];
```

and transform those faces to the $x$-$y$ plane:

```
polys = Polygon[Composition[Drop[#, None, -1] &,
                            RotationTransform[{nrm, {0, 0, 1}}]] /@ facs];
```

See the silhouette:

```
Graphics[polys]
```

[image: cow silhouette]

To make an even simpler silhouette, we can cheat a little by rasterizing and then converting back to a polygon with `ImageMesh[]`:

```
cowPolygon = First[MeshPrimitives[ImageMesh[
   FillingTransform[ColorNegate[Binarize[Graphics[polys]]]],
   DataRange -> RegionBounds[polys]], 2]];

Graphics[cowPolygon, Frame -> True]
```

[image: simplified cow silhouette]

Even further simplification can be done by applying the Douglas-Peucker algorithm to this polygon. Using Szabolcs's [`SimplifyLine[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137945):

```
cowPolygon = Polygon[SimplifyLine[First[cowPolygon], 0.004]];
```

which yields

[image: really simplified cow silhouette]

This can now be used in `Inset[]`. My computer is unable to evaluate the routines for generating the OP's points, so I'll use something different:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; pts = RandomPoint[cow, 500];]
```

Now, a scatter plot:

```
Graphics3D[Inset[Graphics[{Brown, cowPolygon}], #, Center, Scaled[0.015]] & /@ pts,
           Axes -> True, Boxed -> {Left, Bottom, Back}, 
           FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}]
```

[image: a moo-ving scatter plot]