# BezierCurve is different from BezierFunction

Tags: functions, splines, function-comparison

I am constructing Naca type profiles with Bezier curves.

```
controlPoints={{1, 0.}, {0.863924,0.00448168}, {0.78316,-0.019}, {0.444, -0.019}, 
  {0.269064,-0.019}, {0,-0.014478}, {0, 0}, {0, 0.017794}, {0.236028, 0.041}, 
  {0.442,0.041}, {0.616096,0.041}, {0.70006,0.0378152}, {1,0.}};

bezProfile = BezierFunction[controlPoints];

Show[Graphics[{Orange, BezierCurve[controlPoints], Red, 
   Point[controlPoints], Green, Line[controlPoints]},
   Axes -> True], ParametricPlot[bezProfile[t], {t, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: Result]

The `BezierFunction` gives a very different results over the `BezierCurve` which is wrong !!

Any explanation ??

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting questions. See the tag description. If you do suspect a bug, *always* mention your Mathematica version.

Comment: use `BezierCurve[controlPoints, SplineDegree -> (Length@controlPoints - 1)]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SplineDegree->1 does not work with BezierFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8209/splinedegree-1-does-not-work-with-bezierfunction)

Answer (score 6):

Use the option `SplineDegree -> (Length@controlPoints - 1)` with `BezierCurve`:

```
Show[Graphics[{Orange, Thick, 
    BezierCurve[controlPoints, SplineDegree -> (Length@controlPoints - 1)], 
    Red, Point[controlPoints], Green, Line[controlPoints]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[bezProfile[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.01], Opacity[.5]]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

[`BezierCurve >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve.html):

> BezierCurve *by default represents a composite **cubic** Bézier curve.*

```
Graphics[{Orange, Thick, BezierCurve[controlPoints], 
  Thickness[.01], Opacity[.3], Blue, 
  BezierCurve[controlPoints, SplineDegree -> 3]},
Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for swift reply. The BezierFunction does not have SplineDegree as an option only the BezierCurve has Why ?  The correct curve is the last one you plotted with y=0 for x=0 and x=1. Should I split the curve in upper and lower one or are there other solutions.

Comment: @MaartenMostert For composite bezier functions there is `BSplineFunction`

Comment: @MaartenMostert,  can you use `BSplineCurve` and `BSplineFunction` instead of `BezierCurve` and `BezierFunction`?