# How to obtain the function of a plotted Bezier curve?

Tags: function-construction, implementation-details, splines

I have some control points and I could just plot the Bezier curve, but I also  need to have the function! How can I get the exact function of the plotted Bezier curve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the documentation for `BezierCurve`, under *Properties & Relations*, it is written that a Bezier curve can be constructed from a sum of Bernstein polynomials. They give the following example:

```
pts = {{0, -1}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 1}};
Graphics[BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> 3], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[t_] := Sum[pts[[i + 1]] BernsteinBasis[3, i, t], {i, 0, 3}]
ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can read about this relationship on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezierCurve.html).

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can just write `f = BezierFunction[pts]`. See [`BezierFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierFunction.html).

Comment: Please note that `BezierCurve` is different from `BezierFunction`, and by default produces different result: **[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186950/280)**, **[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8240/280)**.

Comment: Get parametric polynomial expression for x and y with `PiecewiseExpand g[t_] = f[t] // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify[#, 0 <= t <= 1] &` yields `{3 t, (-1 + 2 t)^3}` . `ParametricPlot[g[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,   GridLines -> Automatic]`  Get y as a function of x `Solve[Thread[{x, y} == {3 t, (-1 + 2 t)^3}], y, {t}]` yields `{{y -> 1/27 (-3 + 2 x)^3}}`

Answer (score 2):

I've made a function that can convert any BezierCurve of any degree into a set of curves, each parameterized from 0 to 1. First, convert the BezierCurve points to a new set of points:

```
compositeBezierPoints[bezierCurvePoints_, degree_Integer] :=
Select[
  Partition[bezierCurvePoints, UpTo[degree + 1], 1][[1 ;; -1 ;; degree]],
  Length[#] > 1 &]

compositeBezierPoints[bezierCurvePoints_, 1] :=
Select[
  Partition[bezierCurvePoints, UpTo[2], 1],
  Length[#] > 1 &]
```

If you input the points of the BezierCurve, and the degree (Automatic is degree 3), then `compositeBezierPoints` breaks up the points into a new set of points expected by `BezierFunction`. You would map `BezierFunction` over this list to get a list of functions that are each parameterized from 0 to 1. Here's a Manipulate showing the equivalence for a range of degrees:

```
pts = Table[{i, RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, 15}];
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}], 
    ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[Through[(BezierFunction /@ compositeBezier[pts, d])[t]]],
      {t, 0, 1}], 
    Graphics[{Black, Dashed, BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> d]}]],
  {d, 1, 6, 1}]
```

You can re-parameterize the composite parts into a Piecewise function that itself runs from 0 to 1. I use `BezierSymbolicFunction` (found somewhere on MSE) to get the arc lengths in order to scale the segments:

```
BezierSymbolicFunction[pts_?MatrixQ] :=
Function[Evaluate[Sum[pts[[i+1]] BernsteinBasis[Length[pts]-1, i, #], {i, 0, Length[pts]-1}]]]

makeBezierPiecewise[bezierCurvePoints_, degree_Integer] :=
Module[{symbolicSegments, bezierSegments, lengths, ends},
  symbolicSegments = BezierSymbolicFunction /@ compositeBezier[bezierCurvePoints, degree];
  bezierSegments = BezierFunction /@ compositeBezier[bezierCurvePoints, degree];
  lengths = ArcLength[#[t], {t, 0, 1}]& /@ symbolicSegments;
  ends = Prepend[Accumulate[lengths/Total[lengths]], 0.];
  Function[Evaluate[
    Piecewise[
      Table[
        {
          bezierSegments[[i]][(#-ends[[i]])/(ends[[i+1]] - ends[[i]])],
          ends[[i]] < # <= ends[[i+1]]},
        {i, 1, Length[ends]-1}]]]]]
```