# How to blur a line gradually

Tags: graphics, visualization

I would like to draw a line or curve and blur it partially or gradually.
AFAIK `Blurring` is only blurring for a complete object (like a line).
Of course I can clumsily split a line in chunks like below but it's not very useful. Any ideas?

```
b = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {5, 5}}]
xy = Flatten[
   MapIndexed[{Blurring[ First@#2/10 - 1], Line[#1]} &, 
    Partition[Table[b[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.02}], 2, 1]], 1];
Graphics[{Thick, Green, xy}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more precise why your method _is not very useful_? It looks like it's working ...

Comment: @Domen He wants the blurring delta to be continuous

Comment: `CapForm["Round"]` seems to do the best job, but it's not perfect (I think). -- Too bad `Blurring[]` does not work with `VertexColors` (feature request!).

Comment: Not bad, but slow: `b = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {5, 5}}]
xy = Flatten[
   MapIndexed[{Blurring[First@#2/100 - 1], Line[#1]} &, 
    Partition[Table[b[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.002}], 2, 1]], 1];
Graphics[{Thick, Red, CapForm["Butt"], xy}]`

Comment: I wonder if OP might be looking for something more like the answer that currently uses `Opacity` to emulate the `Blurring` effect that they envision. I mention this because they have made comments of wanting the line to stay the same thickness, and also have a worry how some solutions will work with multiple lines. As far as I understand, a true `Blurring` would not satisfy well either of those concerns.

Comment: @CATrevillian yes perhaps I should have been more clear. I was focussed on blurring but the Opacity is closer to what I need. I see many nice methods are presented!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not blurring but maybe close enough to what you want. We create a parametric function from the bezier curve via [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202077/how-to-obtain-the-function-of-a-plotted-bezier-curve) and apply a color function. Feel free to experiment with it. Potentially you can combine it with [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/vary-the-thickness-of-a-plotted-function) to make the function wider and use the opacity of the color function to achieve a similar effect.

```
Clear[points, b, p]
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {5, 5}};
b = BezierFunction[points];
p[t_] := Sum[points[[i + 1]] BernsteinBasis[3, i, t], {i, 0, 3}];
ParametricPlot[p[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[0.3, 1, 1, Max[1 - #, 0.1]] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is closest to what I meant indeed. I now need to figger out what the BernsteinBasis is..

Answer (score 8):

Here is a possible approach using overlapping lines

```
b = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {5, 5}}];
curves = Table[n b[x], {n, 0.9, 1.1, .01}];
styles = Table[{Blue, Opacity[n]}, {n, .01, .4, .04}];

ParametricPlot[curves, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Join[styles, {{Blue, Opacity[0.4]}}, Reverse[styles]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea! I would like to keep the  width more equal.

Answer (score 6):

I will happily delete this if it's not really what you're looking for, but you could convert the plot to an image and then blur with increasingly large kernel Gaussian filters:

```
b = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {5, 5}}]
p = ParametricPlot[b[t], {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHgov.png"]
gF[i_, ker_] := GaussianFilter[i, ker]
takeParts = 
 Table[ImageTake[img, {1, 720}, {(36*(x - 1) + 1), 36*x}], {x, 20}];
```

```
blurred = Table[gF[takeParts[[x]], x/2], {x, Length@takeParts}]
ImageAssemble[blurred]
```

[image]

Comment: thx. I would prefer a graphic approach instead of image. That said I like this approach but wonder how it would work with many closely aligned lines etc.

Answer (score 5):

Following a similar approach to kglr's (now deleted) answer, just with different choices of `ColorFunction` et al.:

```
width = 0.1;
parallel[t_, d_] := b[t] - d Cross[b'[t]]/Norm[b'[t]]
ParametricPlot[parallel[t, d], {t, 0, 1}, {d, - width , width}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, u, v}, 
   Directive[
    Opacity[(1.5 - u) Exp[-(v - 1/2)^2/(2 (u + 0.1) width)^2]]]], 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]